# entity framework error in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I am trying make a join in entity framework and display datas in a label but i get an error like "FileLoadException was unhandled by user code".Here is my codebehind:

```
protected void display() {

         AspNetOrnekEntities entity = new AspNetOrnekEntities();
         var everything = (from insan in entity.insanlar
                           join renk in entity.renkler on insan.SevdigiRenk equals renk.Renk
                           select new
                           {

                               kisiId = insan.KisiId,
                               renkId = renk.RenkId

                           });

         foreach (var data in everything)
         {
             Label1.Text += data.kisiId + "   " + data.renkId + "<br/>";
         }
    }
```

I call "display" in page_load and error comes from that line. I think problem occurs because of first line of the display method because I turned all other lines into comments and problem still occurs. I am using Model1.edmx as connection.

Comment: Try to add this in Webconfig `<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.5.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>`

Comment: Thank you for your reply now i get an error like : "HTTP Hatası 500.19 - Internal Server Error" in browser. Seems like it can't find my "Default.aspx" .

Comment: Could you tell me the Dotnet framework you are using and `EF version` `also

Comment: My EF version is 4.0.0.0 and my dotnet framework is 4.5

Comment: Try to update the EF !!

Comment: I updated it and problem solved. I know it's an easy thing but i wouldn't be able to solve it without your help. Thank you very much.

Comment: If it helps you plz mark / upvote so that other users wont find trouble in figuring this !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update the `EF` using the Package manager Console